# How to stop running services from another activity?

Tags: java, android

I want to stop the services of location updating after making a call function in android.
From main activity I used ACTION_CALL for calling one number.I also used one Location_Listener to update the location.
after calling it stop working of Location_Update.

Comment: you can call it's removeUpdate() method to stop searching location.

Comment: I want to update Location but after making a call..

Comment: that's called restarting it again after making a call :P

Comment: I tried this but it shows Force Close error.
log cat show,the service is not stopped.